# Attribute Value length Limit In Nifi

Tags: attributes, apache-nifi, entity-attribute-value

I have the requirement where I am converting the base64 Image content to attribute and after that I am preparing the payload including the base64 Image content. But the problem is while converting the base64 Image content (approx. 6-7 MB size ) it is getting truncated in the attribute Value.

Can you please tell me what is the length limit of attribute value in NIFI.

Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: it could depend on the way how you are extracting the attribute. btw. why you are extracting image into attribute? why not to do it directly into content?

Comment: Hi @daggett, After that I am preparing payload and one of the field to that payload is file_content due to that i am converting it into the attribute